# Can't disable System Integrity Protection for auxiliary systems on my Apple Silicon mac: "recovery system is not paired with the required volume"

Tags: recovery, sip, apple-silicon

I have an M1 Mac Mini with three macOS systems installed within the same APFS container on the internal drive: Big Sur, Monterey, and the latest Ventura beta.

If I boot into the recovery environment, open terminal and use `csrutil disable` to disable System Integrity Protection on my main system, the Monterey system, it works fine. However, if I try to disable SIP for either the Big Sur or Ventura systems, I get the following error:

```
csrutil: The current recovery system is not paired with the requested volume "[volume UUID]"
Ensure that the booted recovery system matches the main system that is being modified.
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You must load the correct recovery system for its respective volume.

If you have three systems installed you will have three recovery volumes installed so you must boot from the respective recovery system.

Source: [Apple Platform Security: Paired recoveryOS restrictions](https://support.apple.com/guide/security/paired-recoveryos-restrictions-sec4cf9d63a6/web)